# Compare Number of Rows affected

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compare a string (network ID) and using a SQL Like command, return the numbers of rows affected (if the user name was found or not) however in my code I'm always getting " -1 " which i can not find why, the username is correct and found in the SQL table by running a query in SQL Server Mgt.

```
Try
        Dim Con As New SqlConnection
        Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WCRDUSMJEMPR9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MicroDB;Integrated Security=True"
        Con.Open()
        Dim SQL2 As String
        SQL2 = "SELECT * from MicroDB_Users WHERE Users LIKE '+@Usercheck+'"
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(SQL2, Con)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usercheck", TextBox1.Text)
        Dim obj2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery
        Con.Close()
        If obj2 > 0 Then
            MsgBox(obj2)
            Response.Redirect("~\ControlCharts\AddData_Control.aspx")
            Label7_Control.Visible = False
        Else
            MsgBox(obj2)
            Label7_Control.Text = ("You are not authorized to Add Data")
            Label7_Control.Visible = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
```

As you can see, i;m using a IF to compare if the user was found ( 1 row affected) or if it was not found ( 0 rows affected).

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=` ? If you are trying to get network ID, are you using Windows Authentication in your project?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Eddy: I've edited my answer to take your wrong like-syntax into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used for insert,update or delete queries only. So you either have to use `COUNT` in your query and use `ExecuteScalar` or use `ExecuteReader` and the reader's  [`HasRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx) property.

```
Using var reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        ' ...
    Else
        ' ...
    End If
End Using
```

[**ExecuteNonQuery**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx):

> For **UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements**, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.** If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

**Update**: Apart from that you're using the `LIKE` operator and the parameter incorrectly. Instead of

```
SQL2 = "SELECT * from MicroDB_Users WHERE Users LIKE '+@Usercheck+'"
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usercheck", TextBox1.Text)
```

use this approach

```
SQL2 = "SELECT * from MicroDB_Users WHERE Users LIKE @Usercheck"
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usercheck", string.Format("%{0}%", TextBox1.Text))
```

Comment: Based in your feedback, the code worked with some minor modifications to it, thanks for exlpaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows affected is only returned when you do INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE.

> [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)
>
> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

To get the number of rows, use `SELECT count(*) FROM myTable`

`ExecuteNonQuery` is meant for query that does not return rows, obvious from its name `NonQuery`.

For query that returns result, use these instead

- ExecuteReader() - when multiple rows are returned
- ExecuteScalar() - when one row and one column is returned. This will be perfect in your case

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, i'll have it in mind next time!

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows is affected when you write `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE` scripts, not `SELECT` .. Use `SQL2 = "SELECT * from MicroDB_Users WHERE Users LIKE '+@Usercheck+'"` instead and `cmd2.ExecuteScalar()`

```
SQL2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) from MicroDB_Users WHERE Users LIKE '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'";
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(SQL2, Con)
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usercheck", TextBox1.Text)
        Dim obj2 As Int32 = 0
        obj2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar())
```

Comment: It keeps returning 0 however i tried a different approach with Select. Thank you for your feedback!